# Responsive Google Chart Data not working

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, google-visualization

Unfortunately I am not a developer, so I am trying to figure out how it works. I have some knowledge about PHP, HTML and CSS but unfortunately none about JavaScript. Below is my current code of Google Charts Data, it's imported by a module and the javascript code is in places inside the PHP file. Here is my code:

```
$js = "

google.setOnLoadCallback({$funcChart});

function {$funcChart}() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(".json_encode($data).");

    var options = ".json_encode($options).";

    var chart = new google.visualization.{$chart}(document.getElementById('{$container}'));

    chart.draw(data, options);

}";

if(strpos($width, '%') !== false) {

    JHtml::_('JABehavior.jquery');

    $js .= "

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery(window).resize(function(){

            {$funcChart}();

        });

    });

    ";



}



$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

$doc->addScriptDeclaration($js);



require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath($module->module, $params->get('layout', 'default'));
```

}

How do I add a responsive function into the above code? The current chart looks weird on my page; http://goo.gl/v1GVWk
If you open the page and scroll to the "Trekking Map" tab then you will see the chart, but it looks very bad.

Comment: When I open developer console the graph gets fixed... I believe it might be because you draw the chart before you are in in Trekking Map tab, try calling the drawChart funcion after clicking on Trekking Map tab

Comment: What will be the code to do that? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you allowed to use jquery? If not, try changing
<a href="#tab1-trekking-map" onclick="jaDrawChart404()" data-toggle="tab">

Comment: I guess I am allowed to use Jquery. Changing the code you gave me didn't work because when the content is supplied by CMS when browsing the site the is not shown.

Comment: Not sure how to fix it sorry, try adding a timeout of 5-10 seconds before chart loads

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Following Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

google.setOnLoadCallback(initChartExpertBottom);

$(window).on("resize", function (event) {
  initChartExpertBottom();
});

function initChartExpertBottom() {
  var options = {
    legend:'none',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    tooltip: { isHtml: true },
    chartArea: {left: "3%",top: "3%",height: "94%",width: "94%"},
    colors: ['#7CB5EC', '#5C5C61','#16c104'],
    pieHole: 0.50,
    pieStartAngle: -90,
    is3D: false,
    pieSliceText: 'none',
  };

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ["Hide" , (11+2)]                 //addition of value of all elements
  ]);
  drawChartExpertBottom(data, options);
}

function drawChartExpertBottom(data, options) {

  var tooltip = [
    Math.round((11/(11+2))*100) + "%",
    Math.round((2/(11+2))*100)+ "%",
    "Hiii3",
  ];

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

  var sliceid = 0;

  function eventHandler(e){
    chart.setSelection([e]);
    try {
      selection = chart.getSelection();
      sliceid = selection[0].row;
    }
    catch(err) {
      ;
    }
    $(".google-visualization-tooltip-item-list li:eq(0)").css("font-weight", "bold");
    $(".google-visualization-tooltip-item-list li:eq(1)").html(tooltip[sliceid]).css("font-family", "Arial");
  }


  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmousedown', eventHandler);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', eventHandler);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

HTML for above script

```
<div id="piechart"></div>
```

Css for above code snippet

```
<style>
#piechart {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.google-visualization-tooltip{
  display:table;
}
g{
  cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
```